# How to have fresh allure attachments each email?

Tags: selenium, allure, python-behave

Having issue where allure attachments folder never clears and stacks attachments.

I want to have unique attachments each time a build is ran.

I tried creating a folder called `output/`and put all the images in there. But when I attempt to add them as attachments they dont exist and the folder is empty under "workspace"

I can successfully attach images from `allure-report/data/attachments`  but need to clear it after each build without resetting the whole workspace. How can I just get images to attach uniquely from a `output/` folder or from `allure-report/data/attachments` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Just need to install this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/

Then add the workspace cleanup as a post build action.